# Sending PDF file back to client

Tags: odoo

I have made a wizard with a button. On buttons action the function generates a PDF file on the server. How can I send back this file from server disk to the client ?

Comment: Maybe u need to change the web client part

Comment: Thanks, but I´m asking for GTK.

Comment: I'd create it as an attachment object for the object which generated the pdf. If that is not an option, when dig into server code to check which method is used to return an invoice to the webservice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a report, write the PDF file in a binary field.

See the [export language wizard](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/view/4312/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_export_language.py#L44) for example

Comment: That's good. But it is a PDF file created on the server. So will the GTK client open the PDF reader or the "Save as" dialog ...