# Run a report from a wizard

Tags: odoo

I have a wizard with a button. On button action I want to run a report and leave the PDF on the server. I have the above code fragment that creates a report with web service. But in a wizard context I have normally only the uid (I think).

What will be the equivalent way to get the report to disk in a wizard ?

```
def reportToDisk(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    dbname = 'db'
    username = 'user'
    pwd = 'pass'
    model = 'sale.order'
    report_name = 'doc.sale'

    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
    uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

    sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')
    ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, model, 'search',[])[0:1]

    sock_report = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/report')
    id_report = sock_report.report(
            dbname, uid, pwd, report_name, ids,{'model': model, 'id': ids[0], 'report_type':'pdf'}
    )

    cont = True
    while cont:
            report = sock_report.report_get(dbname, uid, pwd, id_report)
            cont = not report['state']

    string_pdf = base64.decodestring(report['result'])
    file_pdf = open('/home/arch-in/file.pdf','w')
    file_pdf.write(string_pdf)
    file_pdf.close()
```

Comment: Why would you use an xmlrpc call to the server, when your code is already running inside the server?

Comment: I won't, but this is a running code example. I'm asking how to do it "inside" the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending PDF file back to client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822684/sending-pdf-file-back-to-client)

Answer (score 2):

Return the report action on your button click(It can be wizard button or view button, it just works with button click return) like following:

```
  def btn_clik_action(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context == None:
            context = {}
        value =  {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml', 
        'report_name':'report.name.(servicename)',
        'datas': {
                  'model':'model.name',
                  'id': ids and ids[0] or False,
                  'ids': ids and ids or [],
                  'report_type': 'pdf'
                 },
           'nodestroy': True
       }
```

Just returning the report action will give you file of the report which basically you don't need to write or anything.

Thank YOu

Comment: This will give me the output of an OpenERP one report, but I'm looking to get a PDF file back that may be produced another non-OpenERP process.

Comment: @PeterMmm: It does return the PDF file to be which you will save in download folder of your browser.